# Filtering listview of custom POJO's by their fields

Tags: java, android, listview, filtering

I have a POJO:

```
public class RoomData implements Parcelable {
    private String objectId, name, building, floor, imageUrl;
    private boolean hasPc, hasProjector, hasTelepresence, hasWhiteboard;
    private boolean dataReady = false;
    private ArrayList<MeetingData> meetingData = new ArrayList<MeetingData>();
    private int capacity;
    private ArrayList<BeaconData> beacons = new ArrayList<BeaconData>();
    private DateTime nextAvailableStart, nextAvailableEnd;
    private boolean availableNow = false;
    private ArrayList<Interval> meetingDuringIntervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
}
```

that is populated into a custom ListView/ListAdapter.

I want to know how I can filter that list by the fields of my `POJO`. For instance if I construct a `RoomFilter` object, that states that my `capacity` integer should be higher than X. How can I implement this? I can only find links to `filtering` by `primitive` data types...

Here is my custom `Adapter` class:

```
public class BeaconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<BLEDeviceAdvertisement> beaconArrayList = new ArrayList<BLEDeviceAdvertisement>();

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    //BeaconAdapter for the custom ListView
    public BeaconAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BLEDeviceAdvertisement> beaconArrayList) {
        this.beaconArrayList = beaconArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return beaconArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public BLEDeviceAdvertisement getItem(int position) {
        return beaconArrayList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //Custom getview for the custom layout beacon_row_item.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myCustomView = convertView;

        if (myCustomView == null)
            myCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_row_item, null);

        return myCustomView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just loop through the list filtering out what you don't need. Or if you need to change filters, you can keep a new list which is a view over the whole list. Then you use the view-over-the-whole-list in the adapter

Comment: Did just that. Works fine. Post it and I will accept as a solution. Thanks @Gil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After OP's request I post my comment as an answer for future reference, giving more details. Here are some possible solutions:

1. Destructive update: Loop through the list, filtering out what you don't need. Implement adapter based on this list.
2. Virtual view: Implement logic for a "virtual view" over the original list. Here you keep only the original list, but in *all* adapter's methods you skip items that don't match the filter. For instance, in `getItem(int pos)` you loop through the list keeping a counter, but you increment it only if the item matches the filter: when the counter equals pos you return the item. Similar for the other methods.
3. Concrete View: Use an additional list to keep the "view" over the original list, so to cache the computation done in 2. When the filter is set/updated, a loop through the original list builds the "view" and then you implement the adapter based on the "view". More time efficient, but also more memory consumed.